# why ellipsis added in one line not in multiple line?

Tags: html, css

I have some text in column (multiple lines ) .I need to add ellipsis when text is large (if text is large more than column height ).I googled it and find a solution from here

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/
and use in my demo .But when I apply it apply only in first line .Mean it truncated all text and add ellipsis in first line

```
.answer_block .option{
        padding: 3em 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em ;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kEplF4kXjIkRRmxNzsVb?p=preview

I need if text coming in large line it truncated in last and add ellipsis in last line.It should should show text upto the column weight and then show ellipsis

Comment: ok ...using number of character count ? example if length is more than 30 it  show ...

Answer (score 0):

`text-overflow: ellipsis;` only works on single lines. There is no pure CSS solution that I am aware of.